# Function to generate a Centroid on the Largest Polygon

Tags: postgis

I am trying to create a function of a common sql routine I run.

Basically it returns the 1 centroid per polygon from a table of polygons (mixed geom types. Has both polygons and multipolygons).

My table is this:

```
  CREATE TABLE poly_and_multipoly (

  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,

  "name" char(1) NOT NULL,

  "the_geom" geometry NOT NULL

);



-- add data, A is a polygon, B is a multipolygon

INSERT INTO poly_and_multipoly (name, the_geom) VALUES (

    'A', 'POLYGON((7.7 3.8,7.7 5.8,9.0 5.8,7.7 3.8))'::geometry

    ), (

    'B',

    'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)), ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'::geometry

);
```

[image: polys]

So far my function looks like this. I am stumbling a bit on the logic of putting my sql statements into the function. I know I need to do a

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
```

... based on the ...

```
ST_Area(the_geom)
```

...of the broken out Multipolygons created with...

```
SELECT id,
    ST_GeometryN(the_geom, generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(the_geom))) AS the_geom
FROM poly_and_multipoly ;
```

...but after that it starts getting a bit hazy (i.e. how to fit this in the function). Any thoughts?

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_it_center(id, the_geom) 
    RETURNS geometry AS $$
    BEGIN
    -- Filter Polygons from Multipolygons
       IF (ST_GeometryType(the_geom) like 'ST_Polygon') then
       ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom)
    -- IF IT is a Multipolygon, Find the Largest Polygon, Return a Centroid
    -- of the largest polygon 
       IF (ST_GeometryType(the_geom) like 'ST_MultiPolygon') then
...
       SELECT 

       RETURN point;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help you get to where you want.

I've done it as a query will handle a complete table, but you can take the general principles and implement it in a number of ways.  I've put your example polygons in as sample data.

```sql
-- Sample data in a CTE for ease of use
WITH Sample AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES (
        'A', 'POLYGON((7.7 3.8,7.7 5.8,9.0 5.8,7.7 3.8))'::geometry
        ), (
        'B',
        'MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,4 0,4 4,0 4,0 0),(1 1,2 1,2 2,1 2,1 1)), ((-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 -2,-2 -1,-1 -1)))'::geometry
        )) A (name,the_geom)
)
-- The query, which could be an update, insert, etc
SELECT name, 
       the_geom, 
       centroid
FROM (
    SELECT name, 
           the_geom, 
           ST_PointOnSurface(part) AS centroid, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ST_Area(part) DESC) AS R
    FROM (
        SELECT name, 
               (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS part, 
               the_geom
        FROM Sample
         ) disaggregated
     ) largestFirst
WHERE R = 1;
```

Comment: PARTITION...is sweet. Thank you. My function is below.

Answer (score 2):

Fewer IF statements...I like!

```sql
 Create or Replace Function as_centroid(polygon geometry)
    RETURNS TABLE (cent geometry)
    Language 'plpgsql' as $$
    Begin
    return query
    SELECT 
           centroid
    FROM (
        SELECT 
               -- the_geom, 
               ST_PointOnSurface(part) AS centroid, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                   --PARTITION BY the_geom -- partition only required for multiple rows  
                   ORDER BY ST_Area(part) DESC) AS R
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  (ST_Dump(polygon)).geom AS part 
                   --,polygon as the_geom -- not required for single rows
             ) disaggregated
         ) largestFirst
    WHERE R = 1;
    END $$;
```

Comment: You can probably drop the parts of the query that carry through `the_geom` and the `PARTITION BY` because you will only be dealing with a single object at a time.  I can make an edit if you like.

Comment: @MickyT ok I th